# Run Excel macro externally with VBS not effective

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have an excel macro that adds certain lines of data to some of the worksheets in an excel workbook. The problem I have is that if i run the macro from within the workbook it all works like a charm, but i am not so lucky when i try to run it externally.

I am using the following VBS code to run the macro but for some reason it does not go as expected. I can see in explorer that the the excel file gets opened ( by the new date modified) but there are no changes in the worksheets inside.

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Create an Excel instance
Dim myExcelWorker
Set myExcelWorker = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

' Disable Excel UI elements
myExcelWorker.DisplayAlerts = False
myExcelWorker.AskToUpdateLinks = False
myExcelWorker.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
myExcelWorker.FeatureInstall = msoFeatureInstallNone

' Tell Excel what the current working directory is 
' (otherwise it can't find the files)
Dim strSaveDefaultPath
Dim strPath
strSaveDefaultPath = myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath
strPath = WshShell.CurrentDirectory
myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath = strPath

' Open the Workbook specified on the command-line 
Dim oWorkBook
Dim strWorkerWB
strWorkerWB = strPath & "\WatchlistMentoring.xlsm"

Set oWorkBook = myExcelWorker.Workbooks.Open(strWorkerWB)

' Build the macro name with the full path to the workbook
Dim strMacroName
strMacroName = "'" & strPath & "\WatchlistMentoring.xlsm!UpdateAllspreads()"
on error resume next 
   ' Run the calculation macro
   myExcelWorker.Run strMacroName
   if err.number <> 0 Then
      ' Error occurred - just close it down.
   End If
   err.clear
on error goto 0 

oWorkBook.Save 

myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath = strSaveDefaultPath

' Clean up and shut down
Set oWorkBook = Nothing

' Don’t Quit() Excel if there are other Excel instances 
' running, Quit() will shut those down also
if myExcelWorker.Workbooks.Count > 0 Then
    myExcelWorker.Quit
    End If

    Set myExcelWorker = Nothing
    Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Obviously the filename and the macro name are correct on their own, but not sure i am using them correct alltogether?

Comment: Take out the `On Error Resume Next`. Do you get an error?

Comment: Oops, Yes I do get an error "The macro may not be available!" 
So how do I refer to the macro correctly ? The filename is WatchlistMentoring.xlsm and the Macro Name is UpdateAllSpreads() stored under Module 1 (not under Worksheet)

Comment: If the workbook it's in is open, remove the path from the `strMacroName`.

Comment: The only other thing to verify is that the macro is within a module, not a sheet or in thisworkbook.  E.g., the target workbook runs a macro when loading from ThisWorkbook and cannot have that called by VBS.

Comment: OK I have got the macro to run now but it does something completely different from what it should. Maybe I try to open the file physically and THEN run the macro ... Thanks for your help anyway!